# What is the correct way of using typing.Literal?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

My code looks something like this, which runs fine BDW without any errors

```
from typing import Literal

def verify(word: str) -> Literal['Hello XY']:
    a = 'Hello ' + word
    return a

a = verify('XY')
```

Although, when I'm trying to do the type-checking using mypy, it throws an error `error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "Literal['Hello XY']")`

NOTE: To perform type-checking simply do `mypy ./filename.py`, after pip installing mypy.

**ALSO**, When I do this, the type-checking works fine

```
from typing import Literal

def verify(word: str) -> Literal['Hello XY']:
    a = 'Hello ' + word
    return 'Hello XY' #changed here

a = verify('XY')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what you are trying to do? The way the function is typed isn't sensible – it can return *any* arbitrary string starting with ``'Hello '``, not just `'Hello XY'`. Note that type annotations are just that – they don't influence how code behaves now whether it is correct (unless some code explicitly inspects annotations).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`word` can be any string, so this seems like a good thing that mypy complains because it cannot guess that you will always call it with the appropriate argument.  In other words, for mypy, if you concatenate `'Hello '` with some `str`, it can give any `str` and not only `'Hello XY'`.

What you could do to check if the function is called appropriately, is instead to type `word` with a literal:

```py
from typing import Literal, cast

hello_t = Literal['Hello there', 'Hello world']

def verify(word: Literal['there', 'world']) -> hello_t:
    a = cast(hello_t, 'Hello ' + word)
    return a

a = verify('there')  # mypy OK
a = verify('world')  # mypy OK
a = verify('you')  # mypy error
```

Note that a cast is still required because mypy cannot guess that the concatenation of `'Hello '` with a `Literal['there', 'world']` is of type `hello_t`.

Comment: Hello @qouify, thanks for the explanation. I see where I was going wrong. 

I still have a question related to the second part of your answer though. Why do we need cast here and what exactly it does? 

I was trying to play around with it, I cant understand. When I do `cast('abc', 'abc')` it returns 'abc' when I do `cast('abc', 'xyz')` it returns 'xyz'.

Comment: `cast` does not do anything: it just returns its second argument.  The only purpose of an expression like `cast(int, i)` is to tell mypy that `i` must be considered as an `int`.  You can think of it as a comment put here to guide mypy.  But it has no runtime implication: you could remove your `cast` from your program and it would run perfectly fine.