# type hinting a specific integer values into python function

Tags: python, type-hinting

**Edit Note:** there is no solution *yet* for this problem, because it's not a problem in the first place.

`mypy` work on checking and not compiling the code. so a code like: `func(input_number)` won't be checked for `input_number` is of value `0 | 1 | 2` because `mypy` does not compile the code and thus doesn't know what is the value of `input_number`

**end of note**

I'm acquiring the skill to *type hinting* my functions and files.

but I ran into a weird situation.

I have a function that *as agreed* can only accept 3 chosen integers as arguments, 0, 1, and 2.
so I made the relational following line of code:

```
def func(number: 0 | 1 | 2):
    print(number)

input_number = 0
func(input_number)
```

but when I enter **`mypy test.py`** I get the following error:

```
test.py:1: error: Invalid type: try using Literal[0] instead?  [valid-type]
test.py:1: error: Invalid type: try using Literal[1] instead?  [valid-type]
test.py:1: error: Invalid type: try using Literal[2] instead?  [valid-type]
```

so I decided to write it using Literal:

```
from typing import Literal

def func(number: Literal[0, 1, 2]):
    print(number)

input_number = 0

func(input_number)
```

but now I got this:

```
test.py:3: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Literal[0, 1, 2]""  [arg-type]
```

my initial guess was `Literal` meant to contain only `str` values, and by so I changed `input_number`:

```
input_number = '0'
```

but the same error occurred with small change:

```
test.py:3: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal[0, 1, 2]"  [arg-type]
```

**I always try to look into other people work and libraries for how they implement different techniques, but I never saw something like this**

**and I know I can ignore errors within `type hints` if my code can work fine. but this was a strange bug for me, and I can't escape the itch**

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435073/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-typing-literal) help ?

Comment: Type `Literal[0 ,1, 2]` means that you will call the function with a literal `0` `1` or `2`, not a variable set to one of those values, such as `func(0)`.  Better practice might be to just  use int,, but either raise a `ValueError` if the input is not 0 1 or 2, or return `None`  in that case, depending on what is appropriate.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I don't have to throw an error for not matching, because the `0` `1` `2` are results of other functionalities that assure that I'm getting these specific values. *but I can add this validation anyway*.
I understand what you mean with passing value vs variable, but I'm already passing value assigned to a variable thought-out the code, and I think it's more important to be consistent.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety that's not true, you can do `x: Literal[0] = 0` and it will work with `func(x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Well, ok yes, if you type hint a variable as a Literal, it will work, but that's only practical for constants,  For the more typical case of a variable that is getting an int value from a user input or another function, its mypy is going to complain that the types don't match.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga NO, because then I would have assigned default value into a function, and python's function has specific way of arranging arguments **positional/keyword/default/arg/kwarg**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's not about changes that I need to make, but it's about having intuitive way of doing it. having `number: 0 | 1 | 2` will result in immediate understanding for *what should be passed*.
but I don't think python's `type hints` has something like `Value[]` or `ReturnValue[]` in it's functionality.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanSheikho I wasn't suggesting you sue a default value, I was explaining how `typing.Literal` works. I'm not sure what you mean by `Value[]`, are you referring to the syntax from some particular language? But basically, what you are asking for is not really available in Python's type system, the closest thing being `typing.Literal`. Again, it isn't clear to me if that is sufficient for your purposes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga with `Value[]` I'm just wishing for equivalent for `Literal`, where `Value[]` is a passed argument during runtime. **I know it's not available in python's type system**, I guess I will ignore `mypy` error and stick with `0 | 1 | 2`

Answer (score 2):

If the typing is required for documentation only, you could use an enum:

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class AcceptedNumber(IntEnum):
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2

def func(number: AcceptedNumber):
    print(number)

input_number = 0

func(input_number)
```

That way, you are also able to reduce the use of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

However, mypy will fail unless you pass an enum value along:

```py
func(AcceptedNumber.ZERO)
```

---

If you want mypy to accept `0`, `1` and `2` as literals, then you could also use `Union`. However, it will be quite verbose...

```py
from typing import Literal, Union

def func2(number: Union[Literal[0], Literal[1], Literal[2]]):
    print(number)

func2(0)
```

Comment: the second code snippet with `Union[Literal[0], Literal[1], Literal[2]]`, `mypy` understand it exactly as `Literal[0, 1, 2]` which is one of my tryout.

I kinda like the first code snippet *as you said "reduce magic numbers"*. but I think it's a little problematic *for making enum that I can't really pass into argument*

Comment: @AbdulrahmanSheikho what do you mean "can't really pass into argument"? Why won't this enum work for you exactly?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanSheikho `Union[Literal[0], Literal[1], Literal[2]]` works for me with mypy.

Comment: @Thomas because in your second code snippet, you haven't assigned `0` to a variable.

doing the following:
`input_number = 0` and `func2(input_number)`
will case the same error:
`error: Argument 1 to "func2" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Literal[0, 1, 2]"  [arg-type]`
meaning that `mypy` changed `Union[Literal[0], Literal[1], Literal[2]]` into `Literal[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: @AbdulrahmanSheikho you could do `input_number: Literal[0] = 0`, in this case, mypy needs the help because of it's inference heuristics, but I think pyright will work here. Of course, if it is the result of some calcualtion, `input_number = x + y` then `typing.Literal` won't work

Answer (score 0):

mypy is a static analyser. If you declare a function to accept a litteral parameter, it will only accept literal values and will never accept any variable. The reason is that the value is a run time thing and mypy is a *compile* time tool.

So you are left with only 2 options:

- declare a Literal parameter and document that the function does require a literal value - rather uncommon approach
- declare an int parameter and control at run time that the parameter has the expected value:

  ```
    def func(number: int):
        if not 0<=number<=2:
            raise ValueError('func only accepts 0,1 or 2 value')
        print(number)
  ```

Comment: well, no, you can do something like `x: typing.Literal[0]  = 0` then do `func(0)` and if `def func(num: Literal[0,1,2])` then it will pass. The problem I think is that `mypy` will infer `x = 0` as `int`. But if the number is coming from the result of some calculation, then it won't work